# Distinguish matplotlib twinx axis for better visibility

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, twinx

When using twinx axis, it is sometimes difficult for the lecturer to distinguish one axis from the other, especially in black and white. I found a plot in an article using a symbol with a circle and an arrow to show which data corresponds to which axis. It's a clever way to do it I think, unfortunately I can't find which symbol it is, someone knows this one?

[image]

The solution is maybe to create it myself like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57555215/matplotlib-secondary-dual-axis-marking-with-circle-and-arrow-for-black-and/57556455#57556455)

Comment: "The solution is maybe to create it myself " - yes very likely.

Comment: @BigBen yes, I'm pretty sure this wasn't made in Python...